# python install zbar error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, zbar

enviornment:

```html
pyenv versions
system
2.7.13
* 3.4.3 (set by /home/foo/.pyenv/version)
3.4.3/envs/venv343
venv343
```

easy_install zbar while encounter the following errors:

```
Searching for zbar
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/zbar/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/5c/bd2a96a9f2adacffceb4482cdd56831735ab5a67ea6a60c0a8757c17b62e/zbar-0.10.tar.gz#sha256=5d0dad77dbca8822a4689c546f598f28030321efb14fa36ac
5e409d181a0d9dd
Best match: zbar 0.10
Processing zbar-0.10.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-oaUXl5/zbar-0.10/setup.cfg
Running zbar-0.10/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-oaUXl5/zbar-0.10/egg-dist-tmp-5Jv6UI
In file included from zbarmodule.c:24:0:
zbarmodule.h:26:18: fatal error: zbar.h: No such file or directory
 #include <zbar.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

as mentioned with this problem on stackoverflow, following procedures already tried but not work:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install bzip2
sudo apt-get install bzip2-dev
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4
sudo apt-get install libbz2
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
sudo apt-get install libevent
sudo apt-get install libevent1-dev
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
sudo apt-get install libgcc
sudo apt-get install libgcc1
sudo apt-get install libgcc1-4.7-dev
sudo apt-get install libgcc1-dev
sudo apt-get install libgcc-4.8-dev
sudo apt-get install libpython3.4-dev
sudo apt-get install libpython3.4-stdlib
sudo apt-get install libpython3-dev
sudo apt-get install libpython3-stdlib
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install openssl
sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev
sudo apt-get install python3.4-devel
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-devl
sudo apt-get install python3-gcc
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install python-devel
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

while install libzbar-dev as some friend suggest, the error info seemed different but still not work

```
Searching for zbar
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/zbar/
Best match: zbar 0.10
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/5c/bd2a96a9f2adacffceb4482cdd56831735ab5a67ea6a60c0a8757c17b62e/zbar-0.10.tar.gz#sha256=5d0dad77dbca8822a4689c546f598f28030321efb14fa36ac
5e409d181a0d9dd
Processing zbar-0.10.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-cw6n9lyu/zbar-0.10/setup.cfg
Running zbar-0.10/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-cw6n9lyu/zbar-0.10/egg-dist-tmp-vbl6ojsc
In file included from zbarmodule.c:24:0:
zbarmodule.h:42:5: error: unknown type name ‘PyIntObject’
     PyIntObject val;            /* integer value is super type */
     ^
zbarmodule.c: In function ‘initzbar’:
zbarmodule.c:112:9: warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
         return;
         ^
zbarmodule.c:115:34: error: ‘PyInt_Type’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     zbarEnumItem_Type.tp_base = &PyInt_Type;
                                  ^
zbarmodule.c:115:34: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
zbarmodule.c:129:9: warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
         return;
         ^
zbarmodule.c:137:13: warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
             return;
             ^
zbarmodule.c:146:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Py_InitModule’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     PyObject *mod = Py_InitModule("zbar", zbar_functions);
     ^
zbarmodule.c:146:21: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
     PyObject *mod = Py_InitModule("zbar", zbar_functions);
                     ^
zbarmodule.c:148:9: warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
         return;
         ^
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

how could i solve this? thank you for all the answers

Comment: Try installing `libzbar-dev`.

Comment: still doesn't work , but the error info seemed different :(

Comment: What version of python are you using? At a glance it looks like you are trying to install on 3.x but the module only supports 2.x.

Comment: Python 3.4.3 with pyenv 1.1.1-5-g7467eec。also has 2.7.13 installed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

from another post seemed irrelevant i figure out the solution

[ImportError: No module named zbar on Linux Mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189513/importerror-no-module-named-zbar-on-linux-mint)

however only zbar-tools not enough for the good result, i put in

sudo apt-get install zbar-

and press the TAB then found zbar-dbg, just for a try, it really worked.

> sudo apt-get install zbar-tools zbar-dbg

it really struck me while gcc errors caused by zbar problem indeed.
maybe some inspire for the similar problem, so i put it here.

Answer (score 3):

On ubuntu and on Mint

`sudo apt-get install python-zbar libzbar-dev python-qrtools`

`pip install libzbar-cffi==0.2.1`

For python3 in more recent ubuntu versions, one needs to change the packages requested for python3 and:

`sudo apt-get install python3-zbar libzbar-dev python3-qrtools`

Answer (score 0):

The zbar_version function requires an patch argument. Try building your own module with: https://github.com/rxwen/zbar.git

pip install git+https://github.com/rxwen/zbar.git